# mapCanvas().DestinationCrs().authid() returns nothing

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, c++

I want to do some work with projections in my c++ application with QGIS API v2.14. But canvas and layers didn't return their CRS. Even when I'm setting it to them with setDestinationCrs() for canvas or setCrs() for the layer they returns nothing anyway. QGIS desktop application returns canvas and layers CRS from console at the same time.
OS is CentOS 7. QGIS API v 1.8 on CentOS 6 has the same problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with adding "**QgsApplication::setPrefixPath("/usr", TRUE);**" before "**QgsApplication::initQgis();**".